# custom class decorator s in Angular - Understanding of mentioned code

Tags: typescript-decorator, angular-decorator

I got the following code from internet for implementing auto unsubscribing from internet:

```
@Component({...})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    notifier = new Subject()
    ngOnInit () {
        var observable$ = Rx.Observable.interval(1000);
        observable$.pipe(takeUntil(this.notifier))
        .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
    }
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.notifier.next()
        this.notifier.complete()
    }
}
```

Instead of using the same code in components in angular app, the following custom class decorator was created:-

```
// For redefining OnDestroy interfacae
export interface OnDestroy {
    readonly destroyed$?: Observable<boolean>;
    ngOnDestroy(): void;
}

// Function to check if the parameter passed is type of "function"
function isFunction(value) {
    return typeof value === 'function';
}

// Class Decorator Factory
export function TakeUntilDestroy(destroyMethodName = 'ngOnDestroy') {

    // Would retrun a modified constructor for the class where this class decotator would be applied
    return <T extends new (...args: any[]) => {}>(constructor: T) => {
    
    // Get access to the method 'ngOnDestroy' on the class
        const originalDestroy = constructor.prototype[destroyMethodName];

    // check if a function with name 'ngOnDestroy' exists or not. if not, throw a warning message.
        if (!isFunction(originalDestroy)) {
            console.warn(`${constructor.name} is using @TakeUntilDestroy but does not implement ${destroyMethodName}`);
        }
    
    // a modified constrcutor would be returned here
        return class extends constructor {
    
      // a new observable would be created
            takeUntilDestroy$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

        // ??    
            get destroyed$() {
                this.takeUntilDestroy$ = this.takeUntilDestroy$ || new Subject();
                return this.takeUntilDestroy$.asObservable();
            }
            
            // ngOnDestroy method present in class is being redefined
            [destroyMethodName]() {
                if (isFunction(originalDestroy)) {
            //??
                    originalDestroy.apply(this, arguments);
                }
                this.takeUntilDestroy$.next(true);
                this.takeUntilDestroy$.complete();
            }
        };
    };
}

// ?? 
export const untilDestroyed = that => <T>(source: Observable<T>) => {
    if (!('destroyed$' in that)) {
        console.warn(`'destroyed$' property does not exist on ${that.constructor.name}`);
        return source;
    }
    return source.pipe(takeUntil<T>(that.destroyed$));
};

//The following is how the above was used in the component:
import { TakeUntilDestroy, untilDestroyed } from '../../../somefilename';

@TakeUntilDestroy()
@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  templateUrl: './my-comp.html'
})

testbservable$: Observable<any>;

    this.testObservable$ = this.mts.buy(buyReqBody);
    this.testObservable$
      .pipe(untilDestroyed(this))
      .subscribe((res: BuyResponse) => {
    // some code
      },
        (error) => {
          // some code
        }
      );
```

This code for auto unsubscribes work. This is based on some performance testing tools provided in chrome.

Can someone help me in understanding the code? I have marked //?? for comments. I have spend good about of time but seems, I could not understand the code fully.

Comment: How property "destroyed$" is accessible in constant the implementation of constant "export const untilDestroyed = that => <T>(source: Observable<T>)"?

Comment: I get it now. The property is available through the class decorator as we have added by modifying the constructor.